# Instead of String Enum, using Union type, and static declarations

Tags: typescript

The following typing plays better in TypeScript than using Enums in my opinion. But is there a way to simplify this? For example a utility type that I might use. IMO we should be able to define Enums that work this way, but alas we cannot to my knowledge.

Explanation of current code:

`StepWizardEventType` limits the values that an event type can be, the `const` is used to access the values themselves in code. The type of the const `{ [prop: string]: StepWizardEventType }`  allows variables/properties to be typed as `StepWizardEventType` and set to one of the values in the const `stepWizardEventTypes`.

```
export type StepWizardEventType = 'cancel' | 'create' | 'init' | 'next' | 'previous' | 'reset' | 'save';

export const stepWizardEventTypes: { [Property in StepWizardEventType]: StepWizardEventType } = {
  cancel: 'cancel',
  create: 'create',
  init: 'init',
  next: 'next',
  previous: 'previous',
  reset: 'reset',
  save: 'save',
};

export interface StepEvent {
  type: StepWizardEventType;
}

// somewhere else in another file...

const event: StepEvent = {
  type: stepWizardEventTypes.cancel // compiler doesn't complain here! yay!
}
```

EDIT: example enum usage makes the compiler unhappy.

```
export enum EventTypes {
  cancel = 'cancel',
  create = 'create'
}

type EventType = 'cancel' | 'create';

interface Dodad {
  eventType: EventType;
}

const doDadInstance: Dodad = {
  eventType: EventTypes.cancel // TypeScript complains here for enums
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the only example I can think of is easier conversion: `stepWizardEventTypes[myStringVariable]` produces you a guaranteed `StepWizardEventType` without having to convince the compiler to let you do that (`MyEnum[myStringVariable]` will anger TS because you cannot index an enum with random strings).

Comment: @VLAZ - Ugh, and my answer below breaks that.

Comment: Thanks for the example! TypeScript doesn't actually complain where you've indicated, though. (I suspect it doesn't do what you want, but it doesn't complain.) Could you post an example using `enum` that breaks, and a separate example using your own structure that doesn't? Just for clarity.

Comment: Is there some reason why the keys and values of `stepWizardEventTypes` are the same?  Are you really going to index into it with a random string?  Like, `stepWizardEventTypes.foobarbaz` should really be of type `StepWizardEventType` and not a type error?  Or, in other words, does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/weeKew) work for your use case?  If not, could you modify your example to show why it doesn't?

Comment: T.J. the compiler complains for sure. jcalz, looks like a winner to me.

Comment: @jcalz Great suggestion and good catch. I updated to [property in type] to no allow random strings so to speak. You solution uses a brand new es addition and caused me to update to es2020, which shouldn't matter after transpiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on feedback from @jcalz. Still think there is room to simplify somehow, but this is better.

```
type enumPropertyKey = { readonly [P in string]: P };

const makeIdEnum = <K extends string>(...kvs: K[]): enumPropertyKey => Object.fromEntries(
    kvs.map(kv => [kv, kv])
) as enumPropertyKey;

// example usage

const stepWizardEventTypes = makeIdEnum('cancel', 'create', 'init', 'next', 'previous', 'reset', 'save');
type StepWizardEventType = keyof typeof stepWizardEventTypes;

export interface StepEvent {
    type: StepWizardEventType;
}

// somewhere else in another file...

const event: StepEvent = {
    type: stepWizardEventTypes.cancel
}
```